# Get an old version of chrome

Tags: google-chrome, version, downgrade

For my job i need to make my app working on chrome 23, is there a way to get this version for test ? I'm looking for a portable version of chrome 23, because i want to keep chrome updated on my pc too.

Thx.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for super user http://superuser.com/

Comment: Use a VM on your desktop, we do legacy IE testing this way.